# Read Data from Notepad File and Store into a Table in SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, notepad

I want my text file data to be saved in a table in SQL server using filing in ASP.NET MVC.

Is this code fine? I am receiving an error in `inrecord` and `dr`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(@"Server=DESKTOP-ORPNA90\SQLEXPRESS2012;Database=Task;Trusted_Connection=True;", SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "target_table";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Text2Table());

    return View();
}

public DataTable Text2Table()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\test\test.txt");
    string input;

    while ((inrecord = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] values = inrecord.Split(new char[] { '|' });

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["column1"] = values[0];
        dr["column2"] = values[1];
        dr["column3"] = values[2];
        dr["column4"] = values[3];
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    sr.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first add columns to datatable (same name of rows) with "datable.columns.add" and inrecord is not declared.
In split you don't need instanciate a new char, simply => string.split('|')

Comment: Can you please provide me code or a link to save notepad file data into sq server table?

Comment: I don't know, i work any day with Oracle. For integrity of datatable, before add rows, you need create datacolumns like dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn("column1", string)) and change inrecord but input.